# Error building sane-backend on debian

Tags: build, sane

I try to build sane-backend on a Debian 8 Testing i686 machine.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var  --enable-avahi

make

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/share/private/src/mf8030/sane-backends/doc'
TEXINPUTS=".:.:$TEXINPUTS" no ./sane.tex
/bin/bash: no: command not found
Makefile:992: recipe for target 'sane-html' failed
make[1]: *** [sane-html] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/share/private/src/mf8030/sane-backends/doc'
Makefile:542: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

At first make failed because fid2eml was not installed and the variable was "no". Now it fails a few statement further down because TEXINPUTS is "no".

Nether for the problem with fid2eml nor the next error I found anything so far.

I do not care for any local documentation, I just want to build the backend "pixma" that seem to be missing in Debian.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because your machine is missing [dlh](http://www.mostang.com/~davidm/dlh.html), a LaTeX-to-HTML converter.  The `configure` script for sane-backends contains a faulty test for dlh; if it fails to detect it then it mistakenly sets the dlh command path to `no`.

Incidentally, I think there may be a typo in your original question.  You write that "fid2eml" was missing from your system, when I think you meant "fig2dev" (which is part of the [transfig](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/transfig) tool suite).  The `configure` test for fig2dev is similarly faulty, and will also lead to the Makefile executing a non-existent `no` command if fig2dev is not found.

*Update:* This problem was fixed in the master branch of the sane-backend source repository on 18 September 2016.